# Slim framework и автозагрузка классов

Tags: framework, php, autoload

После установки фреймворка Slim, в частности этого кода

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
```

у меня перестала работать автозагрузка классов (через __autoload). Слим, похоже, всё на себя взял. Можно ли как-то разрулить эту ситуацию? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал у себя устаревший __autoload.
Поменял на [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php), и всё заработало пучком.